# Springboot java application-mysql CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, linux, networking, jdbc

I'm having a problem with the connection of a Java Spring Boot application to a MySQL database, see in the title, and more: `java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.`

I've installed the application on 3 devices, 1 Linux, 2 Windows, never had such problem.

The Java application is runs on a Debian 10 machine, and the MySQL server also runs there. The Spring datasource url: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/final?useSSL=false&?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

In netstat:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      32528/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      32528/mysqld
```

I can also connect to it with telnet.
In MySQL, database users have all grants, all user hosts set to %.
I've tried setting bind_address in MySQL config, setting users, nothing helped.
Tried ufw allow mysqld, ufw disable too.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If i copy the `application.properties` from the project, into config folder next to the project (which is also loaded by springboot), it just works.

It's the bug of springboot? Hibernate? Or what?